# How to boot from CD/DVD on a Samsung s02ub

Tags: windows, multi-boot, boot

I am trying to install Linux on to my laptop. It's a Samsung. (Samsung np365e5c s02ub)
I was able to access the BIOS by pressing F2 during boot. In the BIOS under "Boot" there's an option that says "Boot Device Priority". When I select it the only option I see is "Boot Options #1 [Windows Boot Manager (P...]"

I have no idea what to do next. I've been reading on Google but I see so many different things. I am assuming after reading my issue has to do with the UEFI settings. Though I could be wrong.

As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the disc in the drive when starting the system up and entering the BIOS?

Comment: Yeah I did. I figured it out. I had to disable secure boot and the boot priority option.The only boot priority option was "Windows Boot Manager" I disabled it and restarted the PC and reentered the BIOS. I also changed the UEIF option to the only other options. "Legacy OS" to the only other options. Then I restarted and re entered the BIOS and then it gave me the option for booting from devices.

Comment: If you solved it, can you click the "Answer your question" button so this question doesn't sit "unanswered" forever?

Comment: Yeah i'll answer it right away with detail. Thanks.